# save Spark dataframe to Hive: table not readable because "parquet not a SequenceFile"

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'd like to save data in a Spark (v 1.3.0) dataframe to a Hive table using PySpark.

The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html) states:

> "spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet: When set to false, Spark SQL will use the Hive SerDe for parquet tables instead of the built in support."

Looking at the [Spark tutorial](http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/5/exercises/data-exploration-using-spark-sql.html), is seems that this property can be set:

```py
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql("SET spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false")

# code to create dataframe

my_dataframe.saveAsTable("my_dataframe")
```

However, when I try to query the saved table in Hive it returns:

```
hive> select * from my_dataframe;
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: 
hdfs://hadoop01.woolford.io:8020/user/hive/warehouse/my_dataframe/part-r-00001.parquet
not a SequenceFile
```

How do I save the table so that it's immediately readable in Hive?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've been there...
The API is kinda misleading on this one.
`DataFrame.saveAsTable` does **not** create a Hive table, but an internal Spark table source.
It also stores something into Hive metastore, but not what you intend.
This [remark](http://mail-archives.us.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201504.mbox/%3CCAAswR-4j668RUMsqZ93EUCDDU-XxTve-e-=tnbemeA=-1P8CpQ@mail.gmail.com%3E) was made by spark-user mailing list regarding Spark 1.3.

If you wish to create a Hive table from Spark, you can use this approach:
1. Use `Create Table ...` via SparkSQL for Hive metastore.
2. Use `DataFrame.insertInto(tableName, overwriteMode)` for the actual data  (Spark 1.3)

Answer (score 3):

I hit this issue last week and was able to find a workaround

Here's the story:
I can see the table in Hive if I created the table without partitionBy:

```
spark-shell>someDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
                  .format("parquet")
                  .saveAsTable("TBL_HIVE_IS_HAPPY")

hive> desc TBL_HIVE_IS_HAPPY;
      OK
      user_id                   string                                      
      email                     string                                      
      ts                        string
```

But Hive can't understand the table schema(schema is empty...) if I do this:

```
spark-shell>someDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
                  .format("parquet")
                  .saveAsTable("TBL_HIVE_IS_NOT_HAPPY")

hive> desc TBL_HIVE_IS_NOT_HAPPY;
      # col_name                data_type               from_deserializer
```

***[Solution]*:**

```
spark-shell>sqlContext.sql("SET spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false")
spark-shell>df.write
              .partitionBy("ts")
              .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
              .saveAsTable("Happy_HIVE")//Suppose this table is saved at /apps/hive/warehouse/Happy_HIVE


hive> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Happy_HIVE;
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Happy_HIVE (user_id string,email string,ts string)
                                       PARTITIONED BY(day STRING)
                                       STORED AS PARQUET
                                       LOCATION '/apps/hive/warehouse/Happy_HIVE';
hive> MSCK REPAIR TABLE Happy_HIVE;
```

The problem is that the datasource table created through Dataframe API(partitionBy+saveAsTable) is not compatible with Hive.(see this [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14927)). By setting **spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet** to false as suggested in the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-metastore-parquet-table-conversion), Spark only puts data onto HDFS,but won't create table on Hive. And then you can manually go into hive shell to create an external table with proper schema&partition definition pointing to the data location.
I've tested this in Spark 1.6.1 and it worked for me. I hope this helps!

Comment: You have posted exactly the same answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341498/save-spark-dataframe-as-dynamic-partitioned-table-in-hive/37504196#37504196). if you think the question is a duplicate, you should mark it as such and not post the same answer twice imo.

Comment: It looks like the code for TBL_HIVE_IS_NOT_HAPPY and TBL_HIVE_IS_HAPPY, is exactly the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: perhaps he intended TBL_HIVE_IS_NOT_HAPPY example to be written by spark with `.partitionBy("ts")`

Answer (score 0):

I have done in pyspark, spark version 2.3.0 :

create empty table where we need to save/overwrite data like:

```
create table databaseName.NewTableName like databaseName.OldTableName;
```

then run below command:

```
df1.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("year","month","day").format("parquet").saveAsTable("databaseName.NewTableName");
```

The issue is you can't read this table with hive but you can read with spark.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

metadata doesn't already exist. In other words, it will add any partitions that exist on HDFS but not in metastore,  to the hive metastore.