# I am getting "Failed with exception java.io.IOException:/user/hive/warehouse/people/part-r-00001.parquet not a SequenceFile

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I created a Spark SQL table by calling .saveAsTable on my dataframe. That command succeeded completely. However, now when I query the table, the parquet files seem corrupt. I'm seeing this error:

```
"Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: hdfs://ip:8020/user/hive/warehouse/people/part-r-00001.parquet not a SequenceFile"
```

below steps I have followed in spark-shell

```
scala >val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
scala>val path="test.json"
scala>val people = sqlContext.jsonFile(path)
scala> people.saveAsTable("people")
```

after that I have opened hive command prompt

```
hive> select * from people;
OK Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: hdfs://IP:8020/user/hive/warehouse/people/part-r-00001.parquet not a SequenceFile Time taken: 0.276 seconds
```

How can I get my hive table(people) result.

Please let me know anything, nay change configuration wise.

How can I resolve above exception.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try setting `spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet` to false

Comment: Hi Sebastian, Thanks for reply

Comment: Hi Sebastian, Thanks for reply.I have done required change based on your suggestion i.e I have add spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet to false in  my "spark-defaults.conf"  like (spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet  false) and then I have restarted my cluster. But still i am getting same error.  can you please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

This may relate to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14927 .

Seems `saveAsTable` will create a Hive table with spark-specific format. If you can see some messages like

> Persisting partitioned data source relation `XX Table` into Hive
>   metastore in Spark SQL specific format, which is NOT compatible with
>   Hive. Input path(s)

then the spark-specific format probably is the cause.

You can create the hive table first with `sqlContext.sql('create table XXX')`. And then put your data in HDFS with `df.write.save`.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239700/spark-sql-saveastable-does-not-compatible-with-hive-when-partition-is-specified) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482798/save-spark-dataframe-to-hive-table-not-readable-because-parquet-not-a-sequence) and [this blog](https://talendexpert.com/tables-saved-spark-sql-dataframe-saveastable-method-not-compatible-hive/)

Answer (score 0):

Tables created with `saveAsTable` won't work from hive if Hive and Spark are using different Parquet SerDe versions, you can try using a different serialisation method

E.g.:

`df.write().format("orc").saveAsTable("table")` or `df.write().format("json").saveAsTable("table")`

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thanks for reply .I have tried above solution it is not working.