# Operation not allowed when creating or inserting Hive table with partitions from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am using Spark 2.2 and I'm trying to create a Hive table based on a dataframe.

I was able to create a new Hive table with data using only:

```
result.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("db.resultTable")
```

When I try to do the same with partitions:

```
result.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).partitionBy("year", "month", "day").saveAsTable("db.resultTable")
```

I always get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Operation not allowed: ALTER TABLE RECOVER PARTITIONS only works on table with location provided: `db`.`resultTable`;
```

**Note:** Altough the error, it created a table with the correct columns. It also created partitions and the table has a location with Parquet files in it (/user/hive/warehouse/db.db/resultTable/year=2017/month=1/day=1). But it contains **no** data.

I tried looking for some answers but haven't find any yet. According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341498/save-spark-dataframe-as-dynamic-partitioned-table-in-hive/31371571), I did everything fine. (I also set the hive.exec.dynamic.partition and hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode)

Does anybody know what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Don't save it as a table but save it as files in the HDFS directory.

```
result.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).partitionBy("year", "month", "day").parquet("/path/to/table")
```