# How to persist a DataFrame to a Hive table?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs, apache-spark-2.0

I use CentOS on Cloudera QuickStart VM. I created a sbt-managed Spark application following the other question [How to save DataFrame directly to Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30664008/1305344).

**build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "1.5.2"
```

I'd like to use a DataFrame as a Hive table as follows:

```
 recordDF.registerTempTable("mytempTable")
 hiveContext.sql("create table productstore as select * from mytempTable");
```

I noticed that I am getting the error:

> The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive  should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx------

I followed other questions and set `chmod 777` for the `/tmp/hive` in HDFS.

It occurred to me know that spark as using local filesystem /tmp/hive.

I did a chmod for local filesystem.

Now I am getting error

> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   MetaException(message:file:/user/hive/warehouse/productstore is not a
>   directory or unable to create one)

I'd like to store a DataFrame in HDFS hive warehouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in play here.

### Issue #1 - Permissions

On CentOS (or other Unix flavours), e.g. Linux or macOS, just do the following:

```
chmod -R 777 /tmp/hive
```

(which should have been done writable for anyone on the OS since it is a temporary directory).

### Issue #2 - Hive Metastore Directory

Since you work with Cloudera QuickStart VM, you use pre-Spark 2.0 (1.6.3 perhaps?).

The issue is due to no `path` specified when persisting a DataFrame to a Hive table.

The directory `/user/hive/warehouse` is used by default and to avoid writing to the directory, define the `path` option when saving to a Hive table using `option` method or `save` with the path option.

```
df.write.option("path", "[path-here]").saveAsTable("tableName")
```

---

As of Spark 2.0, the above line will write to a local Hive metastore (using Derby) which is in the current directory as `spark-warehouse` as specified by `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` Spark property.

To upgrade please define your Spark dependencies using `2.0.2` (not `1.5.2`):

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.2"
```

(Just one single line is all you really need to have Spark SQL with Hive support).

You can then use `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` or `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` to set the Spark warehouse and point to HDFS where the other Hive tables live.