# pyspark 1.3.0 save Data Frame into HIVE table

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark

i am working with spark 1.3.0 (at python)

i have DF :

```
DF.show(3)

ID             Date       Hour     TimeInCluster Cluster Xcluster Ycluster

25342438156 2012-11-30 15:00:00 26            T       130270   165620

25342438156 2012-11-30 16:00:00 86            D       136850   177070

25342438156 2012-11-30 17:00:00 35            D       136850   177070
```

i am tring to save that DF into not exist hive table

how can i do that?

thank you

i change my code to :

```
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

FinalDf.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("myDB.sixuserstablediary")
```

but i got that error

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o280.apply.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "write" among (IMSI, Date, Hour, TimeInCluster, Cluster, Xcluster, Ycluster);
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:162)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.resolve(DataFrame.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.col(DataFrame.scala:436)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.apply(DataFrame.scala:426)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please refer the below link:-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664008/how-to-save-dataframe-directly-to-hive

Comment: i tried but got error 
that my code:

FinalDf.registerTempTable("mytempTable") 

sqlContext.sql("create table sixuserstablediary as select * from mytempTable")

Comment: the error :
    sqlContext.sql("create table sixuserstablediary as select * from mytempTable");
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 528, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._ssql_ctx.sql(sqlQuery), self)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Spark HiveContext

Import Spark HiveContex

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
```

Create a temporary Table from the dataframe then insert into hive table by selecting data from temporary table.

```
// Register the dataframe
   df.registerTempTable("tbl_tmp")

   sqlContext.sql("create table default.tbl_hive_data as select * from tbl_tmp")
```