# Pyspark data frame to Hive Table

Tags: hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to store a Pyspark DataFrame  object to a hive table , "primary12345" is a hive table ?
am using the below code `masterDataDf` is a data frame object

```
masterDataDf.write.saveAsTable("default.primary12345")
```

getting below error

> : java.lang.RuntimeException: Tables created with SQLContext must be TEMPORARY. Use a HiveContext instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save DataFrame directly to Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664008/how-to-save-dataframe-directly-to-hive)

Answer (score 1):

You can create one temporary table.

```
masterDataDf.createOrReplaceTempView("mytempTable")
```

Then you can use simple hive statement to create table and dump the data from your temp table.

```
sqlContext.sql("create table primary12345 as select * from mytempTable");
```

OR

if you want to used HiveContext
you need to have/create a HiveContext

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;

HiveContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc.sc());
```

Then directly save dataframe or select the columns to store as hive table

```
masterDataDf.write().mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("default.primary12345 ");
```

Comment: Thanks this code works but I need to add two more configurations to the  spark application