# Spark count & percentage for every column values Exception handling and loading to Hive DB

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

In the below Scala Spark code, I need to find the count and its percentage of the values of different columns. For this I need to use the `withColumn` method to each and every column like `date`, `usage`, `payment`, `dateFinal`, `usageFinal`, `paymentFinal`.

For each and every calculation I need to use `withColumn` to get the sum and aggregation. Is there any way by which I don't have to write,

```
.withColumn("SUM", sum("count").over() ).withColumn("fraction", col("count") / sum("count").over()).withColumn("Percent", col("fraction") * 100 ).drop("fraction")
```

each and every time? For example as you can see in the below code.

```
var dateFinalDF = dateFinal.toDF(DateColumn).groupBy(DateColumn).count.withColumn("SUM", sum("count").over()).withColumn("fraction", col("count") /  sum("count").over()).withColumn("Percent", col("fraction") * 100   ).drop("fraction")  

var usageFinalDF = usageFinal.toDF(UsageColumn).groupBy(UsageColumn).count.withColumn("SUM", sum("count").over()).withColumn("fraction", col("count") /  sum("count").over()).withColumn("Percent", col("fraction") * 100   ).drop("fraction")  

var paymentFinalDF = paymentFinal.toDF(PaymentColumn).groupBy(PaymentColumn).count.withColumn("SUM", sum("count").over()).withColumn("fraction", col("count") /  sum("count").over()).withColumn("Percent", col("fraction") * 100).drop("fraction")
```

now my code is the below one so can you help we have added conditions for different columns like date,usage,etc (eg in code we have fetch the column containing Date than we have added count and other conditions that we want) now those things we want as dynamic, all the columns name should go inside one yml file and have to read these names from that file, How can I achieve this can anyone help and after reading YML file how I will modify my code please help.

```
object latest

{

 def main(args: Array[String])

  {


  var fileList = new ListBuffer[String]()
  var dateList = new ListBuffer[String]()
  var fileL = new ListBuffer[String]()

  var fileL1 = new ListBuffer[String]()

  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("hbase sql")
  val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
  val spark1 = SparkSession.builder().config(sc.getConf).getOrCreate()
  val sqlContext = spark1.sqlContext


   import spark1.implicits._

    def f1(number: Double)=
     { 
     "%.2f".format(number).toDouble
     }
    val udfFunc = udf(f1 _)   

    def getCountPercent(df: DataFrame): DataFrame =

    {
  df.withColumn("SUM", sum("count").over() )
    .withColumn("fraction", col("count") / sum("count").over())
    .withColumn("Percent", col("fraction") * 100 )
    .withColumn("number", udfFunc(col("Percent")))
    .drop("Percent")
    .drop("fraction")

    }


   def occurenceCount(df: DataFrame,column: String)    
   {

    var usageFinalDF = df.groupBy(column).count.transform(getCountPercent)           

   for (u <- usageFinalDF.collect())
 {
         fileList += column + '~' + u.mkString("~")
  }
}




     val headerCSV=spark1.sqlContext.read.format("CSV").option("header","true").option("delimiter", """|""").load("C:\\Users\\ayushgup\\Downloads\\Header3.csv")

    val columns = headerCSV.columns


  val data =   spark1.sqlContext.read.format("CSV").option("delimiter", """|""").load("C:/Users/ayushgup/Downloads/home_data_usage_2018122723_1372673.csv").toDF(columns:_*)

 for (coll <- columns.toList) 
    {

  if (coll.toLowerCase().contains("date")) 
    {

    for (datesss <- data.select(coll).collect()) 
    {
      dateList += datesss.toString().slice(1, 8)

    }

    var dateFinalDF = dateList.toList.toDF(coll)

    occurenceCount(dateFinalDF,coll)

     } 
    else if (coll.toLowerCase().contains("usage")) 
 {

    var r = data.select(coll).withColumn(coll, when(col(coll) <= 1026, "<=1gb").when(col(coll) > 1026 && col(coll) < 5130, "1-5gb")
      .when(col(coll) > 5130 && col(coll) < 10260, "5-10gb")
      .when(col(coll) > 10260 && col(coll) < 20520, "10-20gb")
      .when(col(coll) > 20520, ">20gb")
      .otherwise(0)).toDF(coll)

      occurenceCount(r,coll)

  } 
  else if (coll.toLowerCase().contains("paymentamount")) 
  {

    var r = data.select(coll).withColumn(coll, when(col(coll) <= 1500, "1-1500").when(col(coll) > 1500 && col(coll) < 1700, "1500-1700")
      .when(col(coll) > 1700 && col(coll) < 1900, "1700-1900")
      .when(col(coll) > 1900 && col(coll) < 2000, "1900-2000")
      .when(col(coll) > 2000, ">2000")
      .otherwise(0)).toDF(coll)

    occurenceCount(r,coll)

  } 
   else if (coll.toLowerCase().contains("accounttenure")) 
  {

    var r = data.select(coll).withColumn(coll, when(col(coll) > 1000000 && col(coll) < 5000000, "1-5m").when(col(coll) > 5000000 && col(coll) < 11000000, "5-11m")
      .when(col(coll) > 12000000 && col(coll) < 23000000, "12-23m")
      .when(col(coll) > 24000000 && col(coll) < 35000000, "24-35m")
      .when(col(coll) > 36000000, ">36m")
      .otherwise(0)).toDF(coll)

   occurenceCount(r,coll)
  } 
  else if (coll.toLowerCase().equals("arpu")) 
  {

    var r = data.select(coll).withColumn(coll, when(col(coll) <= 1500, "1-1500").when(col(coll) > 1500 && col(coll) < 1700, "1500-1700")
      .when(col(coll) > 1700 && col(coll) < 1900, "1700-1900")
      .when(col(coll) > 1900 && col(coll) < 2000, "1900-2000")
      .when(col(coll) > 2000, ">2000")
      .otherwise(0)).toDF(coll)

   occurenceCount(r,coll)

  } 
  else if (coll.equals("DisputeAmount") || coll.equals("ticketsAmount")) 
  {

    var r = data.select(coll).withColumn(coll, when(col(coll) === 0, "0").when(col(coll) > 0, ">0")
      .otherwise(1)).toDF(coll)

   occurenceCount(r,coll)

  } 
  else if (coll.equals("serviceOrdersCreatedLast90Days"))
  {

    var r = data.select(coll).withColumn(coll, when(col(coll) === 0, "0").when(col(coll) === 1, "1")
      .when(col(coll) === 2, "2")
      .when(col(coll) === 3, "3")
      .when(col(coll) > 3, ">3"))
      .toDF(coll)

   occurenceCount(r,coll)
  } 
  else 
  {

    import spark1.implicits._

   val actData1 = data.groupBy(coll).count().transform(getCountPercent) 



    occurenceCount(actData1,coll)

  }
   }

val f = fileList.toList
for (flist <- f) 
   {

   fileL += flist.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "")

   }

   var ff = fileL.toDF()


   var df1: DataFrame = ff.selectExpr("split(value, '~')[0] as 
     Attribute", "split(value, '~')[1] as Value","split(value, '~')[2] as 
     Count","split(value, '~')[3] as Sum","split(value, '~')[4] as 
    Percent");

   }

   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can encapsulate all the `.withColumn()` operations in a function, which returns the `DataFrame` after applying all operations.

```
def getCountPercent(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  df.withColumn("SUM", sum("count").over() )
    .withColumn("fraction", col("count") / sum("count").over())
    .withColumn("Percent", col("fraction") * 100 )
    .drop("fraction")
}
```

Usage:

use `.transform()` to apply the function:

```
var dateFinalDF = dateFinal.toDF(DateColumn).groupBy(DateColumn).count.transform(getCountPercent)
var usageFinalDF = usageFinal.toDF(UsageColumn).groupBy(UsageColumn).count.transform(getCountPercent)
```

Comment: one more help https://stackoverflow.com/users/3846291/vdep , I need to add exception handle in my existing above code , how can I add that ? can you please help me out here.

Comment: @Arush70, you can add the exception handling code in the same function. If you have a specific example, then edit the question. i will answer it

Comment: Hi @vdep I have edited the question I need to know two things one is adding exception handle in this code and other to load the result into hive , please help

Comment: @Arush70, 1) refer this question to save the results to hive table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664008/how-to-save-dataframe-directly-to-hive 2) regarding the exception, exactly pin point where in your code that you want to handle the exception & what are the possible exceptions that you want to handle

Comment: Hi vdep One help needed I used this function def getCountPercent(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  df.withColumn("SUM", sum("count").over() )
    .withColumn("fraction", col("count") / sum("count").over())
    .withColumn("Percent", col("fraction") * 100 )
    .drop("fraction")
}    the output I am getting is "," separated, can I change it ti pipe "|" separated ?? will be really helpful.  https://stackoverflow.com/users/3846291/vdep

Comment: The expected output is a `DataFrame`. Did you convert it to "," seperated String?

Comment: I didn't get, What are you doing on top the `DataFrame` so that you get comma seperated output.

Comment: Hi vdep after the above withColumn operations the result is "," separated and i stored it inside a list as shared with you the above code, the output is as follows        38235885,5,173,2.8901734104046244
accountID,27310249,2,173,1.1560693641618496
accountID,175911421,4,173,2.312138728323699
accountID,158257351,2,173,1.1560693641618496
accountID,232823631,1,173,0.5780346820809248
accountID,228114405,3,173,1.7341040462427744    now the thing is I converted the resultant list to DF split according to "," but the problem occurred when the column value contains some address than split "," is

Comment: so split "," is not giving the count sum or percent as address contains "," inside its values, so can you help here

Comment: change the code where u populate `fileList` to: `for (u <- usageFinalDF.collect()){ fileList += column + "," + u.mkString("|") }`

Comment: on a different note, it not good to `collect` the whole spark `DataFrame` & store it in a scala `List`, it may work for small data, but certainly will fail in future when the data is large.

Comment: Hi vdep it worked really thanks a lot again for your help .

Comment: so can you help me , to get the other way to make the code ?

Comment: hi vdep again one help needed, now I need to check the column conditions like the date,usage and all in the code dynamically for this have to put all these column names inside one yml file, so how can I read that and what change I need to do in my code for the same can you help https://stackoverflow.com/users/3846291/vdep will be really helpful from your end.

Comment: create a new question

Comment: Hi Vdep I have modified this question if needed will add new also do let me know https://stackoverflow.com/users/3846291/vdep

Answer (score 0):

Another way... sort of scala collections - zip/map style :-)

```
scala> val df = Seq((10,20,30),(15,25,35)).toDF("date", "usage", "payment")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [date: int, usage: int ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show(false)
+----+-----+-------+
|date|usage|payment|
+----+-----+-------+
|10  |20   |30     |
|15  |25   |35     |
+----+-----+-------+


scala> df.columns
res75: Array[String] = Array(date, usage, payment)

scala> var df2,df3,df4 = df
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [date: int, usage: int ... 1 more field]
df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [date: int, usage: int ... 1 more field]
df4: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [date: int, usage: int ... 1 more field]

scala> val arr_all = Array(df2,df3,df4).zip(df.columns).map( d => d._1.groupBy(d._2).count.withColumn("sum",sum('count).over()).withColumn("fraction", col("count") / sum("count").over()).withColumn("Percent", col("fraction") * 100 ).drop("fraction") )
arr_all: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = Array([date: int, count: bigint ... 2 more fields], [usage: int, count: bigint ... 2 more fields], [payment: int, count: bigint ... 2 more fields])

scala> val Array(dateFinalDF,usageFinalDF,paymentFinalDF) = arr_all
dateFinalDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [date: int, count: bigint ... 2 more fields]
usageFinalDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [usage: int, count: bigint ... 2 more fields]
paymentFinalDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [payment: int, count: bigint ... 2 more fields]

scala> dateFinalDF.show(false)
2019-01-25 04:10:10 WARN  WindowExec:66 - No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+----+-----+---+-------+
|date|count|sum|Percent|
+----+-----+---+-------+
|15  |1    |2  |50.0   |
|10  |1    |2  |50.0   |
+----+-----+---+-------+


scala> usageFinalDF.show(false)
2019-01-25 04:10:20 WARN  WindowExec:66 - No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+-----+-----+---+-------+
|usage|count|sum|Percent|
+-----+-----+---+-------+
|20   |1    |2  |50.0   |
|25   |1    |2  |50.0   |
+-----+-----+---+-------+


scala> paymentFinalDF.show(false)
2019-01-25 04:10:50 WARN  WindowExec:66 - No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+-------+-----+---+-------+
|payment|count|sum|Percent|
+-------+-----+---+-------+
|35     |1    |2  |50.0   |
|30     |1    |2  |50.0   |
+-------+-----+---+-------+


scala>
```

Note that I have broken down and included `var (df2,df3,df4) = df` so that it will be easy to follow the steps.

They can all be combined like this.

```
scala> val Array(dateFinalDF,usageFinalDF,paymentFinalDF) = Array(df,df,df).zip(df.columns).map( d => d._1.groupBy(d._2).count.withColumn("sum",sum('count).over()).withColumn("fraction", col("count") / sum("count").over()).withColumn("Percent", col("fraction") * 100 ).drop("fraction") )
dateFinalDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [date: int, count: bigint ... 2 more fields]
usageFinalDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [usage: int, count: bigint ... 2 more fields]
paymentFinalDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [payment: int, count: bigint ... 2 more fields]

scala>
```