# inserting Data from list in a hive table using spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of Filename, FilePath and FileSize I want to insert these details into my hive table using spark SQL.

```scala
var fs1 = FileSystem.get(sparksession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
var file_path = fs1.listStatus(new  Path("path")).filter(_.isFile).map(_.getPath).toList
var new_files = fs1.listStatus(new  Path("path")).filter(_.isFile).map(_.getPath.getName).toList
var file_size = fs1.listStatus(new Path("path")).filter(_.isFile).map(_.getLen).toList
var file_data = file_path zip new_files zip file_size

for ((filedetail, size) <- file_size){
  var filepath = filedetail._1
  var filesize: Long = size
  var filename = filedetail._2
  var df = spark.sql(s"insert into mytable(file_path,filename,file_size)  select '${file_path}' as file_path,'${new_files}' as filename,'${file_size}' as file_size")
  df.write.insertInto("dbname.tablename")
}
```

It's generating this insert query:

```sql
insert into mytable(file_path,filename,file_size) select  'List(path/filename.txt,path/filename4.txt,path/filename5.txt)' as file_path,'List(filename.txt, filename4.txt, filename5.txt)' as filename,'List(19, 19, 19)' as file_size;
```

and I'm getting an error:

> mismatched input 'file_path' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'VALUES', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'MAP', 'REDUCE'}(line 1, pos 34)

I want to insert data in table format

```sh
file_path                 filename      file_size
path/filename.txt         filename.txt  19
path/filename4.txt        filename4.txt  19
path/filename5.txt        filename5.txt  19
```

Can someone please suggest me how should i insert data like above?

is there any way to again split this query into 3 different insert hive statements.

```
    insert into mytable(file_path,filename,file_size) select 'path/filename.txt' as file_path,'filename.txt' as filename,'19' as file_size;
    insert into mytable(file_path,filename,file_size) select 'path/filename3.txt' as file_path,'filename3.txt' as filename,'19' as file_size;
    insert into mytable(file_path,filename,file_size) select 'path/filename4.txt' as file_path,'filename4.txt' as filename,'19' as file_size;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create a list containing all the rows and each row will have 3 elements. Create a dataframe and then persist the data using dataframe.

[refer this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664008/how-to-save-dataframe-directly-to-hive)

Comment: @H Roy I have checked this post for its not helpful in my case.As first i m taking all the filenames and size from directory so it can vary every-time.i.e. 5,6....n files.I need to insert all those details in my hive table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in multiple ways.

First, you can convert  a list into a `RDD`

```scala
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(fs1.listStatus(new  Path("path")).filter(_.isFile).map(_.getPath).toList)

// then you can convert the rdd into a dataframe

import spark.implicits._

val df1 = rdd1.map((value1, value2, ....) => (value1, value2,....)).toDF("col1", "col2", ....)

// from the dataframe you can create a temporary view

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table")

// then you can load the temporary view in your table

sqlContext.sql("""
        INSERT [INTO | OVERWRITE] my_hive_table SELECT * FROM my_table
           """)
```